# Nested looping of a function

Tags: python

I have code to plot particle trajectories until all the spaces in a portion of a 3D matrix are filled. This is based on the final position of the particle. A simplified simulation of particles in a beam of radiation traveling through a body.

I was able to use a for loop to plot a whole bunch of particle trajectories together, and to get the number it takes to fill up all the spaces. I did this by, 
'''

```
n = 100
for n in range(particles):
    Path(ax,body)
    if body==[[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]:
        print('Tumor destroyed after particle number', n)
        break
plt.show()
```

'''

and I get the number of particles (n). But I want to loop this many times and then get an average of the number (n) it takes to fill all the spaces in the matrix (destroy the tumor). I tried doing '''

```
trials=10
for i in range(trials): 
    for n in range(particles):
        Path(ax,body)
        if body==[[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]:
            print('Tumor destroyed after particle number', n)
            break
```

'''
but i just get the same n value from the first part of code 10 times. How do I get it to do the first bit of code new each time and get different n values to average them.

the if statement is the condition for the path of the particle to end.

The numbers that come out should all be different since I am using random numbers for the calculations. The calculations are being done inside the Path function. I just want to run the first snipet of code multiple times and am not sure how to execute it.

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but recreating `[[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]` at every iteration is very wasteful. This is a constant expression and will never change. Make it once outside your loop, and then reference it.

Comment: We really have to know what `ax`, `body`, and `Path` are before your call to `Path(ax, body)`.

Comment: The provided code snippets don't cause `n` to be the same value in every iteration. The problem is probably inside the `Path` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a fresh copy of the initial `body` (and possibly `ax`) in each trial.

Something along these lines:

```
import copy

# No need to create this more than once.
empty_body = [[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

trials=10
for i in range(trials):
    test_body = copy.deepcopy(body) 
    for n in range(particles):
        Path(ax, test_body)
        if test_body == empty_body:
            print('Tumor destroyed after particle number', n)
            break
```